# Get Thumbnail for Display in Google Site Search

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to display a thumbnail along with search results when utilizing Google Site Search. Note that I'm using Google Site Search with their XML API and not Google Custom Search Engine. I make a request to the service and parse the data. I can get things like title, snippet, and the url just fine, but it doesn't seem to be giving me the thumbnail url in the response.

My questions are thus:

1. Is there a way to get the thumbnail using the XML API?
2. Where is it located in the XML as I clearly cannot find it?